# Is $\mathbb Z_3+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf i+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf j+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf k$ a local ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, noncommutative-algebra, quaternions

I consider the quaternion division ring on $\mathbb Q_3$: that is
$$\mathbb H_{\mathbb Q_3}=\{a+b\mathbf i+c\mathbf j+d\mathbf k \mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q_3\}$$
with $\mathbf i^2=\mathbf j^2=\mathbf k^2=\mathbf i\mathbf j\mathbf k=-1$. Is the subring
$$\mathbb Z_3+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf i+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf j+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf k$$
a noncommutative local ring, i.e., does it have a unique maximal left ideal (or equivalently a unique maximal right ideal)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Wait... what are $\mathbb Q_3$ and $\mathbb Z_3$ supposed to be?  At first I thought $\mathbb Z_3$ was supposed to be the integers mod $3$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_3=3$-adic numbers.

Comment: By local non commutative ring you mean ...

Comment: That every element is a unit or nilpotent?

Comment: yes, non commutative: has a unique maximal left ideal (or equivalently has a unique maximal right ideal)

Comment: @joaopa "every element a unit or nilpotent" is not equivalent to what you said (and what you said is the standard definition, imo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $-1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}_3$, then the Hilbert symbol is trivial: $(-1, -1)_{\mathbb{Q}_3} = 1$. This means that $\mathbb{H}_{\mathbb{Q}_3}$ is split, i.e., $\mathbb{H}_{\mathbb{Q}_3} \cong M_2(\mathbb{Q}_3)$, the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices. (So in particular it is not a division ring.) Then $\mathbb Z_3+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf i+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf j+\mathbb Z_3\mathbf k \cong M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$, which indeed has the unique maximal ideal $M_2(3 \mathbb{Z}_3)$.

For reference, see $\S12.4$ of [this book](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/quat-book.pdf).

Comment: I agree with the conclusion that $\Bbb{H}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ splits when extended to $\Bbb{Q}_3$. But what is the reasoning again? $-1$ is a square in $\Bbb{Q}_5$, but that extension also splits the rational quaternions. Also, $-1$ is not a square in $\Bbb{Q}_2$, but that extension does not split $\Bbb{H}$. The discriminant of $\Bbb{H}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ is a power of two (Hurwitz order is maximal) meaning that $\Bbb{Q}_2$ and, of course, $\Bbb{R}$ are the only completions where the division algebra is not split.

Comment: Or have I misunderstood something [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162612/11619)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess you're right and the fact that $-1$ isn't a square doesn't really matter: $(a,b)_{\mathbb{Q}_3} = 1$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}_3^\times$. The various possibilities for the value of the Hilbert symbol are given on p. 170 of my reference, and I just focused on the entry relevant to this question. But the underlying reasoning is the same as in Keith Conrad's comment: the quadratic form $\langle -1, -1, -1 \rangle$ is isotropic, which allows us to find a zero divisor.

Comment: (I'm a little wary of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ since things are strange when the residue field has characteristic $2$, but the table for the Hilbert symbol is also given in that case on the following page.)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: +1 very helpful answer, although in the end the ring is *not* local in the standard sense (by having a unique maximal right ideal).  It’s easy to display numerous nontrivial idempotents in this matrix ring.